# Project Reactor: How does blockLast() work?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

From the documentation for blockLast():

`Subscribe to this Flux and block indefinitely until the upstream signals its last value or completes. Returns that value, or null if the Flux completes empty. In case the Flux errors, the original exception is thrown (wrapped in a RuntimeException if it was a checked exception).`

Let's say for an example code sample:

```
    Flux
            .range(0, 1000)
            .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("i = " + i + "Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .flatMap(i -> {
                System.out.println("end"+ i + " Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return Mono.just(i);
            }).blockLast();
```

If I were to understand this based off the documentation's own description, I'd think `blockLast` means to block the publisher (in this case till all 1000 integers are emitted successfully, last one included).

After which .flatMap(..) is called, one at a time (since we don't specifically force parallel processing.

However I see the following in the console when run:

```
i = 0Thread: main
end0 Thread: main
i = 1Thread: main
end1 Thread: main
i = 2Thread: main
end2 Thread: main
i = 3Thread: main
end3 Thread: main
i = 4Thread: main
end4 Thread: main
i = 5Thread: main
```

Isnt `i = 0Thread: main` supposed to run till `i = 1000Thread: main` first then `.flatMap` gets executed?

i.e.

```
i = 0Thread: main
i = 1Thread: main
i = 2Thread: main
i = 3Thread: main
i = 4Thread: main
.
.
end1 Thread: main
end2 Thread: main
end3 Thread: main
```

The behavior is exactly the same if `.subscribe()` is used. I'm kinda confused here.

Answer (score 0):

The observed behaviour is fine. A Flux describes a sequence of operations that are executed as elements are emitted.

So, in your example, each integer generated by `range` is immediately processed by the next operation in chain, i.e. flatMap here.

It is the same behaviour as with standard java.util.stream.Stream API.

The reason for that behaviour is double:

- Avoid buffering all elements between each processing step
- A data source can emit an infinite number of messages. And it can also emit messages with various frequency (with constant delay, or not, very fast or very slow, etc.). So, a stream API is designed to process and return each element as soon as it is received, independently of the messages before or after it.

And about blockLast specifically: internally, it subscribe to the flux, and wait for completion or error signal to return or throw an error to the user.

Comment: So in a sense, its not actually blocking? Speaking of error, I also noticed .subscribe() doesn’t throw an error back to the main thread i.e within the try-catch if i surround the reactive chain w one, but blockLast() does where I can catch the exception successfully in the catch loop. Why is that so?

Comment: subscribe is asynchronous. It means that when you call subscribe, it launch processing in the background, then return immediately. Therefore, it cannot throw the error to your calling thread, because it is not working on the calling thread. blockLast, on the other hand blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous subscription sends completion or error signal.